# Write to a file using PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, fopen

Bassicly what I want to do is using PHP open a xml file and edit it using php now this I can do using fopen() function.
Yet my issue it that i want to append text to the middle of the document. So lets say the xml file has 10 lines and I want to append something before the last line (10) so now it will be 11 lines. Is this possible. Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.domnode-insert-before.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how large that file is, you might do:

```
$lines = array();
$fp = fopen('file.xml','r');
while (!feof($fp))
   $lines[] = trim(fgets($fp));
fclose($fp);

array_splice($lines, 9, 0, array('newline1','newline2',...));

$new_content = implode("\n", $lines);
```

Still, you'll need to revalidate XML-syntax afterwards...

Comment: okay after the 9 what is the 0 for. And where you have newline1 and newline2 is that where i would put information?

Comment: See the [array_splice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) documentation for details. 9 is the position at which to insert new elements. 0 is the number of elements after index 9 which you want to replace (none, in your case, I presume?) and those are followed by a replacement array.

Comment: okay so this looks good but it looks like you closed $fp does this still save the new text?

Comment: bad idea ... use proper xml parsing

Comment: @ajreal I know. That's why I hinted on revalidating syntax. Still there's less overhead (providede the file is relatively small) in comparison to using a XML parsing facilies, which can only parse and (if at all) reconstruct an limited way...

Comment: It's not a charm, it's getting done what you asked. For more complex data manipulation I would recommend methods suggested in the other answers, though. Thanks for accepting.

Comment: You know, you could just have used `file()` instead of a `while` loop. Also, you don't need to read the entire file to write something in the middle...

Comment: @netcoder I agree with using `file()` for brevity, but it does nothing else than slurping the whole file. Tell me, how would you get to change the middle of a file without reading it entirely?

Comment: @goreSplatter: see my answer below.

Comment: file_get_contents() is much easier than fopen/fgets/fclose.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to modify a file from the middle, use the `c+` open mode:

```
$fp = fopen('test.txt', 'c+');

for ($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
   fgets($fp);
}

fwrite($fp, "foo\n");
fclose($fp);
```

The above will write "foo" on the fifth line, without having to read the file entirely.

However, if you are modifying a XML document, it's probably better to use a DOM parser:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->load('myfile.xml');

$linenum = 5;
$newNode = $dom->createElement('hello', 'world');

$element = $dom->firstChild->firstChild; // skips the root node
while ($element) {
    if ($element->getLineNo() == $linenum) {
        $element->parentNode->insertBefore($newNode, $element);
        break;
    }
    $element = $element->nextSibling;
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Of course, the above code depends on the actual XML document structure. But, the `$element->getLineNo()` is the key here.